# how can i hide a <td> from print page in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing, hide

i have a table contains lot of td. i want to hide one of them from print page in the browser when i click print button. how to do that?
this is the index page code:

```
<div id="div_print"><table class="table table-bordered">
<tr class="info">
    <th dir="rtl">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.a)
    </th>
    <th dir="rtl">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.b)
    </th>
    <th dir="rtl">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.c)
    </th>
        </tr>
      </div>
       @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <tr>
      <td>
        @{
        ViewData["class"]= "text-uppercase";
        }
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.a)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.b)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.c)
    </td>
       <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.z}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.z}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.z}, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    </td>
</tr>
  }
  </table>
```

i want to hide this part:

```
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.z}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.z}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.z}, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to do that:

```
@media print
{    
    .not-printable, .not-printable *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Then add the `not-printable` to the element you do not want to print:

```
<div class="not-printable"></div>
```

[CSS 3 Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)